# Why won't my substr call work with the → character?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm building a WooCommerce site for a client using WordPress at the moment and I've written a piece of code that dynamically generates tables with products and product attributes in them. When I call the get_title() method, it gives me a title with the product's parent product first, the "→" sign, then the actual title of the product. I wrote this code to remove the "→" sign and everything before it.

```
$name_raw   = $product->get_title();
$name       = substr($name_raw, ($pos = strpos($name_raw, '→')) !== false ? $pos + 1 : 0);
```

It used to work perfectly, but not anymore. This code also works perfectly with every other character I've put in to test it, but not with that stupid little arrow. It seems like a recent update to something I'm using must've removed this method's ability to handle non-conventional characters. Can anyone recommend any possible solutions?

Comment: just use the multi byte versions

Comment: Any idea how I can find out what it is for the → character?

Comment: @MarvinLazer, I think Ghost means using [`mb_substr`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) instead of `substr`.

Comment: I tried replacing substr with mb_substr but it didn't work. The problem is that the number of characters before the arrow sign are variable.

Comment: Problem has been solved! For the sake of helping out someone with a similar issue, Faisal Mudhir's solution clued me in to the fact that WordPress had converted the character to it's HTML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a WP environment title, the right arrow character probably has been entered using the WP form for a post. I think this character would be converted to it's HTML code, one of these:

```
&rarr; 
&rightarrow; 
&RightArrow; 
&srarr; 
&ShortRightArrow;
&#x02192;
&#8594;
```

So I'd do something like this:

```
function no_right_arrow_name($name_raw) {

    if (empty($name_raw))
        return $name_raw;

    $right_arrows = array(
        '&rarr;',
        '&rightarrow;',
        '&RightArrow;',
        '&srarr;',
        '&ShortRightArrow;',
        '&#x02192;',
        '&#8594;'
    );

    $name_new = $name_raw;

    // removes all possible combinations of right arrows
    foreach ($right_arrows as $right_arrow)
              $name_new = str_replace($right_arrow, '', $name_new);

    return $name_new;
}

$name_raw   = $product->get_title();
$name       = no_right_arrow_name($name_raw);
```

Comment: Wasn't exactly what I was looking for, but you gave me the info I needed to fix the problem! Thank you!

Comment: @MarvinLazer no problem. Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you to solve the issue.